# (re-writing the text file and keep previous data)get value and write in notepad/ms-word- every time in new line of notepad file

Tags: java, file-io, line, jtextfield

I know how to get value from JTextField and Write it into a text file in Java language.
Here is my code :

```
public class createfile {
    private Formatter x;

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            x = new Formatter("c:\\definition.txt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    private void addRecords() {
        x.format(null, jTextField3);
    }

    public void closFile() {
        x.close();
    }
}
```

It works properly and writes the value of jTextField3 to a file called "definition.txt". BUT If the user runs the program again, and enters new value in jTextField3, then "definition.txt" will be filled with new data ! and the previous data will lost !
I do not want to be like that ! I want to keep all the data which every time enters by user.
how should I change my code ?
Thank you !

Comment: I don't see what the references to notepad or ms word in the title or tags refer to. A text file is a text file, no matter what program you use to view it. The JTextField isn't really relevant for this answer either. @SunnY, would you edit the question to change those things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to *append* to the file instead of *overwriting* it. The [`Formatter` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a file name doesn't seem up to the job. I suggest you create a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) where you can explicitely require appending. You can pass that stream to the [`Formatter` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter%28java.io.OutputStream%29) instead of the raw file name.

```
x = new Formatter(new FileOutputStream("c:\\definition.txt", true));
```

Comment: I changed the code to what you have said. but no result ! entering info in textfield for the second time will save the new data in file.txt but it erases previous data in the notepad. any other solution?

Comment: `file.txt` or `definition.txt`? Could it be you're mixing up file names?

Comment: And as my comment to your question indicates, I still don't see what notepad has to do with all this, so it might be there is some misunderstanding there, causing my answer to not be applicable at all.

Comment: Sorry.I mean a text file called "definition.txt"                        in my code, the value of textfield is saved to definition.txt but each time the file loose previous data and updates  with new data from text field. I want to keep all the data which user enters in textfield in several attemps.

Comment: This should work (see the API here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String, boolean) ). Are you sure you are not affecting the file in some other way? Is the file closed when you run the program, or is it open in Notepad or some other app at the same time?